# Update Panel breaks RadioButtonList's OnSelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, updatepanel

Here you can see my html code. I need to run OnSelectedIndexChanged event but I have to prevent post back all page. What should I do?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upRemittance">
            <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblRemittance" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblRemittance_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

RadioButtonList binding method:

```
  List<remittance> remittances = _mainService.RemitanceActiveList().ToList();
            if (remittances.Count > 0)
            {
                rblRemittance.DataSource = remittances;
                rblRemittance.DataTextField = "BankName";
                rblRemittance.DataValueField = "RemitanceId";
                rblRemittance.DataBind();
            }
```

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy OnSelectedIndexChanged event doesn't called.

Comment: @Roar then you have any suggestion to prevent post back?

Comment: Show how you binding radiobuttonlist

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy you can see what you want to see in my question.

Comment: @cagin not exactly. Do you wrap binding code by `if(!IsPostBack)` check?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy yes I do it in page load

Comment: Honestly I tried to emulate you example and all works.

Comment: May be because of one of javascripts which I use? Is this possible? A javascript can block OnSelectedIndexChange event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it with ajax call.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type = radio]").each(function (index, value) {
            $(value).click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:2782/TestPage.aspx/GetBank",
                    data: "{id:" + value.defaultValue + "}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#dvBankInfo").empty();
                        $("#dvBankInfo").append(data.d);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```